# Set ProductVersion dynamically while installing msi

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vbscript, windows-installer, setup-project

I have a windows setup project in VB.Net (in VS 2010). The **ProductVersion** is set to default(1.0.0.0) when I build the MSI.

Now I want to set the ProductVersion dynamically while installation (with the help of a custom action or something like that) reading from a database table, so that after installation of the msi, the Version of the product shown in windows control panel or installed exe file properties, is the updated one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? I.e. basically that looks like sort of "fooling" the system. Can't you just set the ProductVersion to the correct value when you build MSI (that's common practice)?

Comment: yes. but the productversion should be dynamically set from the database value, not set manually for each version. Basically the database team would be responsible for the version management, not the programming team, thus I thought of this process..

Comment: You could add a custom action to your project (.vbproj) to set that version on build (i.e. to pull that value from the "database", whatever it is, and set it to variable which you can use in the installer file). Note that you can use environment variables and project properties in WIX file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that - the ProductVersion is something that Windows uses before it even starts the install. That's why you sometimes see "another version of this product is already installed". The easiest way for someone else to change the ProductVersion after your build and before the install is to use a script to update ProductVersion in the Property table of the MSI. If you look at WiRunSQL.vbs in the Windows kit SDK and know the SQL to use that'll do it. You'd need to update Property.ProductVersion. Docs here with a link to examples:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372021(v=vs.85).aspx